# error in read data from file and sending it via pipe to another process

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I want to create a system that consist of two processes communicating via pipe. The first process reads the content of a file and write it to pipe, while the second one print it out on the terminal. I write the programs but the receiver process don't receive the data correctly when the file has multiple lines. it removes a character from the beginning of the line at each iteration. Any clue please to solve this problem

p1 code

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
#define NAMED_PIPE "./namedpipe"

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("The usage of this program is:\n");
        printf("execute cmd.txt\n");
        return;
    }
    /* initialize the pipe and fork variables */
    int fd;
    char *infile = argv[1];
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    FILE *in;
    in = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (in == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file %s\n", infile);
        return;
    }

    fd = open(NAMED_PIPE, O_WRONLY);

    while (fscanf(in,"%s",buffer)>0)
    {
        write(fd, buffer, (strlen(buffer)+1));
    } 
    fclose(in);
}
```

while p2

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
#define NAMED_PIPE "./namedpipe"

int main()
{ 
    int fd,ret;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    ret=mkfifo(NAMED_PIPE,0666);
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        printf("Error creating the named pipe");
        exit (1);
    }
    fd = open(NAMED_PIPE, O_RDONLY);
    while(1)
    {
        if (read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            printf("read [%s]\n",buffer);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to debug this?

Comment: Can you show sample input and output?  One thing you should realize is that your writes and reads may not pair up the way you think.  For example if you write `a` followed by `b` you might expect to read `a` and `b`.  But you might read `ab` instead.  So you need to be careful, especially if you write null characters to your pipe (which you do).  If you wrote `"a\0"` `"b\0"` to the pipe you might read the whole thing at once and think you had one string to print instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

You define a buffer of 10 characters and read input file with `fscanf`. RTFM `fscanf` is to be used for formatted input and **NEVER EVER** use a raw `%s` to input text but always limit the size of the input to the size of your field. Here it should be at least `"%9s"` to leave one place for terminating null.

But in fact to read unformatted text, the proper function is `fgets`. So in pt1, you should have :

```
fd = open(NAMED_PIPE, O_WRONLY);

 while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), in) != NULL)
 {
    write(fd, buffer, (strlen(buffer)));
 } 
 close(fd);
 fclose(in);
}
```

In pt2, you should leave a place for a terminating null and manually add it, because read only read bytes and give you the number of bytes. You should at least write :

```
while(1)
{
    if ((ret = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1)) > 0)
    {
        buffer[ret] = '\0';
        printf("read [%s]\n",buffer);
    }
    else
    return;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, when i print number of read bytes it always give me one, but print more than one character. I try the code with different variations of strings in the file, when i increase number of characters gradually it works fine, but when i write a short string a fetr a long one it doesn't work.

Comment: @blackiris did you notice that in my code I  add a terminating null at the end of the characters read ?